# Palindrome/mini-Palindrome in string

Tags: c

I need to check if a given string is a Palindrome or mini-Palindrome.
Palindrome length will be 2 or more, the function need to ignore spaces and ignore the differences of upper and lower alphabet.
if the string is Palindrome the function will transfer the indexes of the start and the end of him and will return 1 else return 0.
example1: "My gym" the function will transfer low=0 high=5 and 1
example2: "I Love ANNA" the function will transfer low=7 high=10 and 1
example3: "I love Pasta" return 0.

Also i can’t use functions from librarys other then string.h stdlib.h stdio.h.

I tried to write like this:

```
    int i;
int size = strlen(str);
i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    //-------------------
    if (str[i] >= ‘a’ && str[i] <= ‘z’)
        str[i] = str[i] - 32;
    if (str[size-1] >= ‘a’ && str[size-1] <= ‘z’)
        str[size-1] = str[size-1] - 32;
    //-------------------
    if (str[i] == str[size-1])
    {
        *low = i;
        *high = size-1;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        size--;
        i++;
    }
}
return 0;
```

But it isnt working well, i cant figure how to do it with the example 2

Comment: What is 97? etc. 32 me thinks is space - better wrote as ' '

Comment: Perhaps `tolower` should be used - google that

Comment: yes sorry for not mention but i cant use tolower i needed to do this on my own

Comment: You can use ` ` or  `a` instead of the decimal values.

Comment: Please write `if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')` instead of `if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)`, otherwise your code is very hard to understand. Also, instead of `32`, it would be clearer to write `('a' - 'A')`.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use the standard library's `tolower` function, then you should probably write your own function which does the same. If you instead try to write all of your program's logic into one function, without dividing your code into functions, it will be both harder to program and harder to understand your program.

Comment: ..  A macro will do

Comment: Note that using `if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')` will work on all character sets based on 7-bit US-ASCII (which are most character sets), but it will not work on some character sets in which the letters are not stored consecutively, such as [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). The ISO C standard does not require character sets to store the letters consecutively. However, for the purposes of the exercise, you are probably allowed to assume that they are stored consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes. Will this help you

```
#define LOWER(a) (((a) >=' A' && (a) <= 'Z') ? ((a) - 'A' +'a') : (a))
#define MYCMP(a,b) (LOWER(a) == LOWER(b))

    int is_palidrome(char *s) {
      int start = 0;
      int end = strlen(s) - 1;
       
      for (; s[start] // Not end of line
             && end >=0 // Not run over the from of the line
             && start < end // Still not got to the middle
             && MYCMP(s[start], s[end]) == 1; // They are still equal
             start++, end--) { //Nowt  }
      };
    
      return (start >= end);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a program. It works only if the string contains letters and spaces. You can modify it to work for other characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int isPalindrome( char *s, size_t l );

int main() {
    
    char str[SIZE];
    size_t i, j, len, pldrm = 0;
    
    fgets(str, SIZE, stdin);
    
    len = strlen(str);
    
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) if( str[i] != ' ' && !((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')) ) goto the_end;
    
    for(i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
        
        if( str[i] != ' ' ) {
        
            for(j = i+1; j < len; j++) {
            
                if( (pldrm = isPalindrome(&str[i], j-i+1)) ) {
                
                    str[j+1] = '\0';
                    goto the_end;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
the_end:
    
    pldrm ? printf("A palindrome has been found from the position %zu till the position %zu.\n\nThe palindrome is: %s\n", i, j, &str[i]) : puts("No palindromes");
    
    return 0;
}

int isPalindrome( char *s, size_t l )
{
    static const char az[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", AZ[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int isPldrm = 1, spc = 0; // used to skip spaces within the palindrome

    for(size_t i = 0; i < l/2; i++) {
        
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            
            if( s[i] == az[j] || s[i] == AZ[j] ) {

                while( s[l-1-i-spc] == ' ' ) ++spc;
                
                if( s[l-1-i-spc] != az[j] && s[l-1-i-spc] != AZ[j] ) {
                    isPldrm = 0;
                    goto thats_it;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
thats_it:
    
    return isPldrm;
}
```

Also, it finds only the first palindrome in the input. Doesn't check for further palindromes.